# request.writeFields.size() does not count fields updated with "serverTimestamp()"

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Since there's no simulator for Firestore yet, I can't be 100% sure of what I'm stating.

But, from my tests, using `request.writeFields.size()` in the rules document will not count fields updated with `firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()`.

For example, if the following code is executed:

```
db.collection("myCollection").doc(id).update({
    someString: 'abcd',
    someTimestamp: new Date("October 13, 2014 11:13:00")
    anotherTimestamp: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
})
```

A write rule requesting that `request.writeFields.size() == 3` will fail and a permission error will be returned. If it's changed to `request.writeFields.size() == 2`, then it works.

Similarly:

`'someString' in request.writeFields` will return `true`.

`'someTimestamp' in request.writeFields` will return `true`.

`'anotherTimestamp' in request.writeFields` will return `false`.

Could this be a Firestore bug, or am I missing something?

Comment: Please file a bug with your steps to reproduce.  https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/

Comment: Also make sure your `serverTimestamp()()` isn't a typo.

Comment: Done. // I know this has already been requested multiple times, but a simulator or something better for Firestore rules would really help. Debugging on a trial & error basis is really time consuming.

Also, thanks, it was a typo. Fixed it.

Comment: You can also file a feature request for that.  The more voices the better.

Comment: Just did that haha, thanks @DougStevenson