# request.writeFields.size() counts fields set with “serverTimestamp()" twice

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Problem is similar to [request.writeFields.size() does not count fields updated with “serverTimestamp()”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49310166/request-writefields-size-does-not-count-fields-updated-with-servertimestamp)

but otherwise and little more complex.

I'm trying to write documents with one and two fields, both with and without `options : SetOptions.merge()`

Swift:

```
db.collection(collectionName).document().setData(["time" : FieldValue.serverTimestamp()]) 
db.collection(collectionName).document().setData(["time" : FieldValue.serverTimestamp()], options: SetOptions.merge())
db.collection(collectionName).document().setData(["user": "test",
                                                  "time" : FieldValue.serverTimestamp()])
db.collection(collectionName).document().setData(["user": "test",
                                                  "time" : FieldValue.serverTimestamp()], options: SetOptions.merge())
```

Firestore rules:

`request.writeFields.size() == 1` - False with options and True without options for any number of fields.

`request.writeFields.size() == 2` - True with options and one field. False in other cases.

`request.writeFields.size() == 3` - True with options and two fields. False in other cases.

And so on.

Same with existing document.

Date() instead of FieldValue.serverTimestamp() is OK with the above cases but
`'time' in request.writeFields` is False without options and True with. With FieldValue.serverTimestamp() `'time' in request.writeFields` is always True.

Could this be a Firestore bug, or am I missing something?